# Import .cer certificate from Windows command line

Tags: command-line-interface, certificate

Tired of wading throug MMC jungles, I need a way to import a given `.cer` file (which contains just a public key) into machine-wide certificate store (don't know how is it called in English since I'm using a localized version of Windows) into "Personal Certificates" folder. Both `cmd.exe` or PowerShell versions will be fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Powershell solution, using **System.Security.Cryptograpy.X509Certificates**:

```
$filename = "MyFileName.cer"

[Reflection.Assembly]::Load("System.Security, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=Neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")

$cert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2($filename)

$store = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store([System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreName]::My,[System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreLocation]::LocalMachine)

$store.Open([System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.OpenFlags]::ReadWrite);

$store.Add($cert);
```

Sorry for all the full namespace specifications, but there's no "using" directive in PowerShell.

Comment: It's all those pesky reflection.Assemblies that I need to learn ... Will be stealing this for later use.

Comment: last line of the script misses '$' in front of cert: `$store.Add($cert);`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to import it from the command line, but you don't need MMCs in order to install a certificate, double-clicking on it is just enough.

Answer (score 0):

**This is wrong. See Massimo's post with the powershell reflection assembly.**

---

Uh ... the powershell way is to open the MMC. [Technet Link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347615.aspx)

*This command opens the Certificates MMC snap-in to manage the specified certificate.*

```
invoke item cert:\CurrentUser\my\6B8223358119BB08840DEE50FD8AF9EA776CE66B
```

Comment: How does this relate to importing a .cer file, exactly?

Comment: This is to say, you can't import a cert from powershell, you need to use the mmc. The mmc can be invoked from powershell. I've been down-voted twice, but no one has posted anything to the contrary.

Comment: You've been downvoted because you posted something quite unrelated to the question asked...

Comment: BTW, your answer is actually incorrect, because in PowerShell you have access to the full .NET framework, and System.Security.Cryptograpy.X509Certificates has all you need.

Comment: Lol, fair enough. I see you've posted the REAL answer. Thanks!